How can a reinforcement learning model optimize a value function that it learns dynamically?
I'm exploring the idea of training a reinforcement learning model to optimize a value function that isn't predefined but is learned dynamically by the model itself. In standard RL frameworks, the value function (e.g., state-value or action-value function) is typically estimated using methods like Temporal Difference learning or Monte Carlo simulations. This estimated value function then guides the policy optimization process.
However, I'm curious about approaches where the value function is not statically learned or separately estimated but is an integral part of the model's own learning process. This seems somewhat analogous to how humans learn: our perception of value or reward evolves based on experiences, leading to self-organizing behavior and adaptive decision-making.
My questions are:

Are there existing reinforcement learning methods where the value function is dynamically learned by the model itself, perhaps influencing its own learning objectives in real-time?

How does this concept relate to human learning in the brain? Specifically, how is the human brain different in terms of self-organization and the expansion or specialization of neural circuits actively learning specific tasks, rather than processing inputs uniformly across the entire network?

In biological neural networks, synapses play a crucial role by adjusting the strength of connections between neurons, facilitating learning and memory. Modern artificial neural networks simulate synaptic weights but might lack the dynamic adaptability of biological synapses. Is there a way to incorporate more synapse-like mechanisms into neural network structures to allow for self-organization and dynamic learning of value functions?



Right now from your question, it is very hard to tell what you mean by "approaches where the value function is not statically learned or separately estimated but is an integral part of the model's own learning process". I think you need to expand on that with some details and/or example of what you mean. Also, ask just one question please - you can always ask the other ones later, separately.
